# Какой формат дат лучше подходит для API?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Необходимо в формате json отправлять/получать даты по API. Как обрабатывать и хранить временные зоны?

Заметил, что даты из `NSString` в `NSDate`с временными зонами автоматически конвертируются в UTC.

```
// date with time zone
NSString *dateString = @"2016-11-08T07:00:00.000+11:00";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ";

dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"CDT"];
NSLog(@"1. CDT date    = %@", [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString]);

dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];
NSLog(@"2. UTC date    = %@", [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString]);

dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
NSLog(@"3. system date = %@", [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString]);

// date without time zone
dateString = @"2016-11-08";
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";

dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"CDT"];
NSLog(@"4. CDT date    = %@", [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString]);

dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];
NSLog(@"5. UTC date    = %@", [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString]);

dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
NSLog(@"6. system date = %@", [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString]);
```

Лог:

```
1. CDT date    = 2016-11-07 20:00:00 +0000
2. UTC date    = 2016-11-07 20:00:00 +0000
3. system date = 2016-11-07 20:00:00 +0000
4. CDT date    = 2016-11-08 06:00:00 +0000
5. UTC date    = 2016-11-08 00:00:00 +0000
6. system date = 2016-11-07 21:00:00 +0000
```

Это значит, что для корректной обработки даты надо по строке определять временную зону и рядом с датой `NSDate` хранить временную зону `NSTimeZone`?

```
NSString *dateString = @"2016-11-08T07:00:00.000+03:00";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterForPrint = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatterForPrint.timeZone = [self timeZoneFromDateString:dateString];
dateFormatterForPrint.dateFormat = @"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss";

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"date is: %@", [dateFormatterForPrint stringFromDate:date]);
```

Лог:

```
date is: 08.11.2016 07:00:00
```

Comment: NSDate всегда в UTC (время в мире вообще одно). Для отображения переводите в нужную timeZone.

Comment: Из документации: NSDate содержит точку во времени не зависимо от календарей или временных  зон.

Comment: Советую отправлять в timestamp-формате, если нету цели именно таймзону

Comment: таймзона обязательно нужна. Похоже единственное решение, это отправлять 2 поля timestamp + timeZoneOffset

Comment: Ну это скорее не единственное, но правильное. Вообще тут как - `NSDate` полностью отвязан от таймзоны, он зранит момент времени, а не дату/время. То есть при парсинге полюмомк придётся выпаршивать это в два поля - таймзона и таймстамп. Отправлять можно именно в конкретной таймзоне с указанием её в строке, для этого выставляем форматтеру `timeZone` и юзаем `stringFromDate:`. На вход идёт обычный `NSDate`, ну только подготовить его миенно так, чтобы он показывал нужное время в нужной таймзоне. А сервер уже опять же берёт твою строку и вычленияет из неё отдельно таймзону и таймстамп

Comment: а почему бы на сервере не хранить все в utc, и уже на клиенте не конвертировать в текущий временной пояс

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я пользуюсь тремя правилами:

1. внутреннее представление NSDate - всегда UTC.
2. При взаимодействии с сервером надо использовать UTC и не заморачиваться с ритуальными танцами
3. При отображении или парсинге времени, введенного на стороне клиента надо испльзовать NSDateFormatter с текущей локалью. IOS/Mac OS разберется, какое в данный момент время установлено на конкретном клиенте. Можно завдвать/использовать любой формат, но предполагается, что юзер всегда использует текущее местное время.

Ближайшая аналогия - таблица авиарейсов. Сами самолеты летают по UTC, но для пассажиров и время отлета, и время прилета всегда указываются в местном времени.

Answer (score 0):

При хранении данных на сервере используйте числовой вид даты, измеряемый в секундах от 1970 года, при обработке данных в клиенте используйте NSDate